# Delete only some char from a string

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to delete only ',' which are located before ']'. I tried with:

> arbre={"name":"flare","children":[{"name":"Algèbre","children":[{"name":"Nombres
>   Fractionnels","children":[{"name":"Addition
>   fractionnelle","size":8.333333333333334},{"name":"Division
>   fractionnelle","size":10.0},]},{"name":"nombre
>   entier","children":[{"name":"division
>   entière","size":15.0},]},]},{"name":"Geometrie dans
>   l'espace","children":[{"name":"projection dans
>   l'espace","children":[{"name":"sous chapitre1 projection dans
>   l'espace","size":10.0},{"name":"sous chapitre2 projection dans
>   l'espace","size":15.0},]},]},{"name":"Physique","children":[{"name":"Onde","children":[{"name":"Onde
>   circulaire","size":15.0},]},]},]}

```
 for(i=0; i<arbre.length(); i++) {
      if (( arbre[i] == ',') && (arbre[i+1] == ']' )){
           arbre = arbre.replace(arbre[i],'')
      }
 }     

 println"nouveauarbre="+arbre
```

But with this code all ',' are delete and not only which are located before ']':

> nouveauarbre={"name":"flare""children":[{"name":"Algèbre""children":[{"name":"Nombres
>   Fractionnels""children":[{"name":"Addition
>   fractionnelle""size":8.333333333333334}{"name":"Division
>   fractionnelle""size":10.0}]}{"name":"nombre
>   entier""children":[{"name":"division
>   entière""size":15.0}]}]}{"name":"Geometrie dans
>   l'espace""children":[{"name":"projection dans
>   l'espace""children":[{"name":"sous chapitre1 projection dans
>   l'espace""size":10.0}{"name":"sous chapitre2 projection dans
>   l'espace""size":15.0}]}]}{"name":"Physique""children":[{"name":"Onde""children":[{"name":"Onde
>   circulaire""size":15.0}]}]}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
arbre = arbre.replaceAll(",]", " ]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `,]` with `]`.

```
",]".replaceAll(",]", "]")   // ""
",],".replaceAll(",]", "]")  // ","
",],,".replaceAll(",]", "]") // ",,"

arbre.replaceAll(",]", "]")
```

Try [here](http://ideone.com/kxsQqW).